# unzipping gz file in R

Tags: r

Some R code that used to work to download and unzip .gz files from PubMed is no longer working. Here's a reproducible example:

```
filez = "pubmed22n1148.xml.gz"
url = paste('ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/updatefiles/', filez, sep='')
zipped.file = download.file(url = url, destfile=filez) 
gunzip(filez)
```

The error is:

```
Error in readBin(inn, what = raw(0L), size = 1L, n = BFR.SIZE) : 
  error reading from the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readBin(inn, what = raw(0L), size = 1L, n = BFR.SIZE) :
  invalid or incomplete compressed data
```

I'm using R version 4.1.1 and `gunzip` is from the `R.utils` package version 2.11.0. The files do not appear to be downloading correctly, as I can use `gunzip` on a manually downloaded .gz file.  I've experimented with different methods for `download.file`.

Comment: Add `method = "auto"` to the `download.file` call.

Comment: Adding `method = auto` gave the same error.

Comment: Right, `R.utils::gzip(filez)` is what you want.

Comment: With R4.2 the `download.file` didn't work on Windows. So the `method` fixed that.